# Software & update / Additional pilots

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I can’t put my graphics card: Nvidia GTX 960M has the place of others, in application & updates when I try to choose the Nvidia driver it gives me back to the basic one, Nvidia x settings does not work

here’s the video that shows what I tried:
sorry for the quality :'(

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-M28EQVR1w&feature=youtu.be

driver device

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jBTp.png

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu!

You seem to have way more drivers than you need. Try to remove them and then reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: not works ... , when i finish the autoinstall i get this  : Errors were encountered during execution:  /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430_430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @meVSnoob  try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to resolve that issue

Comment: i re-test but its same

Comment: @meVSnoob The reinsall did not work, so try to reconfigure dpkg with the command and then reinstall again.

Comment: i don't have anything when i want to configure : https://postimg.cc/MnDRPZ1r

Comment: @meVSnoob Just purge Nvidia again. Then try again to install 418 at Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove older Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

add the graphics-driver PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install (and activate) the latest Nvidia graphics drivers
First check the version you want on the [graphics drivers PPA homepage](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410
```

Note: you can change the version later:

[image]